# Let $a,b,c \in G$ and $G$ is a group, prove that the following items have the same order...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a,b,c \in G$ and $G$ is a group, prove that the following items have the same order...

1. $a$ and $a^{-1}$
2. $ab$ and $ba$
3. $abc$ and $bca$

For the first, I see that I have to operate $a^{-1}$ n times to convert $\underbrace{a*\cdots *a}_n = e$ in $e$ but for the others I can't find the way...

Comment: Hint: $(ba)^n = b(ab)^{n-1}a$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(bca)^n=e$.

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
(abc)^n&=a(bca)^{n-1}bc\\
&=a(bca)^{n-1}(bca)a^{-1}\\
&=a(bca)^na^{-1}\\
&=aea^{-1}\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$